# JPA correctly add and remove with oneToMany

Tags: java, jpa

Given the following structure

```
class Company {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Customer> customers;
}

class Customer {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

1) create a company: `Company comp = new Company();`

My question now is how to correctly add a customer:

`Customer cust = new Customer(); 
cust.setCompany(comp);`

Is this sufficient? Or do I add it to "both" sides?

`cust.setCompany(comp);
company.getCustomers.add(cust)`

Same thin with deletion? Say I want to delete the customer:
I delete the customer: `entityManager.remove(cust)`. Is this sufficient?
Or do I need to do a `company.getCustomers().remove(cust)` as well?

Answer (score 0):

If that is sufficient, totally depends on your configuration. For example attached or detached objects in the entity manager. I assume you have your objects detached (in our projects that's usually the case).

> Is this sufficient? Or do I add it to "both" sides?

No and no.

It's not yet sufficient, you can, but don't have to add it to both sides. You could also reload the detached object Company, and it should contain the new customer.

Deletion works the same way, it should be gone when you have the company object reloaded.

The reason is simple: the only mapping is in customer, using company_id. If this is gone, the relation is gone, but you still have caching and memory to think about.